# Magento2 : How can I share session of one magento store with another magento store with different domain?

Tags: magento2, customer, login

Here I have same user and data exists on abc.com and xyz.com. I want to login into abc.com at that time same session need to created for xyz.com. So once user login into abc.com he will have his login into xyz.com also. Please provide some help on this.

Comment: have you achieve this, i am also looking for same.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-sso/ You can check any single sign on plugin to implement this functionality